# Remmina alternative

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

Does anybody know any good alternative for Remmina (doesn't have to be free)?
RDP would be the most important protocol for me.

Remmina is extremely buggy lately. Segfaults every now and then, clipboard share sometimes works, sometimes it does not and if I open a RDP session too fast, the whole application just freezes.

EDIT:
Because of an unrelated reason, I reinstalled fresh ubuntu 12.10, but  my remmina problems are still there. I noticed that remmina supports clipboard-exchange for pictures, gut rdesktop didn't. That was also a reason for a crash.
I also tested 2x, but I couldn't even find a shortkey for switching between local and remote session.

Comment: I recently found itap (http://itap-mobile.com/desktop/rdp) and 2x (http://www.2x.com/rdp-client/windows-linux-mac/) and I'm goint to try it. Does anybody have any experience with one of those yet?

Comment: If all you want is rdp, use freerdp.

Comment: doesn't remmina use freerdp?
So shouldn't most problems appear there too?

Comment: It depends on why remmina is crashing, sounds like a good experiment to me though.

Comment: thats true, I will try that to reproduce some bugs.
Although a GUI would be nice to manage the connections.

Answer (score 9):

- [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/)
- [KRDC](http://www.kde.org/applications/internet/krdc/)
- [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/)

For an up-to-date list of alternatives check out alternativeTo:
http://alternativeto.net/software/remmina/?platform=linux

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

2X is a very nice and stable application 
http://www.2x.com/rdp-client/windows-linux-mac/

Comment: This is a really nice piece of software. Works perfectly fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, 2X software is well developed, or at least works really nice. Also has very nice Android apk to use RDP on your tablet.

Comment: link is dead but here is alternative http://www.parallels.com/eu/products/ras/download/client/

Answer (score 3):

rdesktop?

though it might be worth mentioning: remmina is not buggy for me in the ways that you describe; there might be an underlying issue on your system.  (the only real remmina bug I experience is that the 1-click "resize to client" button tends to expand to fill the screen vertically whether it needs to or not.)

Comment: rdesktop was used by ubuntu before, it doesn't support the newest features. 
but maybe it's worth a shot to purge remmina completely and reinstall

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to point out that now Remmina is actively developed and works quite nicely, with plenty of new features.

If you have specific needs or bugs to report, submit a new issue on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues)

Answer (score 1):

I agree it's buggy, for example, see this bug that has been ongoing for years:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/794415

From reading the bug it appears `freerdp` is the problem and this solves the above bug:
`sudo apt-get purge remmina-plugin-rdp`. Of course, removing the RDP plugin kind of defeats the purpose most people use it for.

On my system fresh Ubuntu 13.10 it doesn't even start up anymore, even after changing `XKBLAYOUT="us"` in `/etc/default/keyboard/`.

`rdesktop` seems like a fine alternative though. It also supports copy and paste in remote session to local session which is why I started using remmina in the first place.

Comment: I also experienced rdesktop as an okay alternative, but I miss some options like automatic resolution recognition or a proper dual monitor handling

Answer (score 0):

You can search for an application called Vinagre a.k.a Remote Desktop Viewer from the Ubuntu Software Centre.
It supports VNC and RDP.
I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.3LTS x64, fresh install. Remmina does not launch at all.
Vinagre works.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on remina 
Vinagre Remote Desktop Viewer
Vinagre is a remote desktop viewer for the GNOME desktop
Its in the software center
just make sure you use the right Protocol on the dropdown menu

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  This adds nothing to the answers that exists already.  When you have enough [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to comment and upvote other posts.  Until then, stick to concrete questions and answers.